# Hibernate loading could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to do a simple app with Spring and Hibernate. I am trying to select the list of articles in the database. the entites Articles and Fournisseurs. a fournisseur has a list of articles.
it's a Maven project.
The view will display the article list and Fournisseur list.

i'm getting the following error:

```
    Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_70_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM70_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE70_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_70_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_70_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_70_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_66_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE66_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE66_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_66_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_70_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM70_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE70_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_70_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_70_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_70_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_66_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE66_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE66_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_66_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_70_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM70_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE70_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_70_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_70_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_70_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_66_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE66_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE66_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_66_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_70_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM70_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE70_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_70_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_70_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_70_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select articles0_.ID_ARTICLE as ID1_67_, articles0_.TYPE_ARTICLE as TYPE2_67_, articles0_.NOMENCLATURE as NOMENCLA3_67_, articles0_.DESIGNATION as DESIGNAT4_67_, articles0_.UNITE as UNITE67_, articles0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT6_67_, articles0_.QUANTITE as QUANTITE67_, articles0_.SEUIL_MINIMUM as SEUIL8_67_, articles0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE9_67_, articles0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE10_67_, articles0_.FOURNISSEUR as FOURNIS11_67_ from ARTICLES articles0_
ERROR: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at com.gest.stock.entities.Fournisseurs_$$_javassist_2.getNom(Fournisseurs_$$_javassist_2.java)
    at com.gest.stock.modele.FonctionDAO.update_table_article(FonctionDAO.java:159)
    at com.gest.stock.vue.VueAcceuilUtilisateur$2.actionPerformed(VueAcceuilUtilisateur.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at com.gest.stock.entities.Fournisseurs_$$_javassist_2.getNom(Fournisseurs_$$_javassist_2.java)
    at com.gest.stock.modele.FonctionDAO.update_table_article(FonctionDAO.java:159)
    at com.gest.stock.vue.VueAcceuilUtilisateur$2.actionPerformed(VueAcceuilUtilisateur.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Articles.java:

```
    public class Articles implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6066869813064596156L;

    private Long id_article;
    private String type_article;
    private String nomenclature;
    private String designation;
    private String unite;
    private String description;
    private Long quantite;
    private Long seuil_minimum;
    private Timestamp date_ajout;
    private Timestamp date_modification;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "articles")
    private Collection<LignesCommandes> lignesComandes;

    @ManyToOne
    private Fournisseurs fournisseur;

    public Articles() {
        super();
    }   

    public Articles(String type_article, String nomenclature,
            String designation, String unite, String description,
            Long quantite, Long seuil_minimum, Timestamp date_ajout,
            Timestamp date_modification) {
        super();
        this.type_article = type_article;
        this.nomenclature = nomenclature;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.unite = unite;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantite = quantite;
        this.seuil_minimum = seuil_minimum;
        this.date_ajout = date_ajout;
        this.date_modification = date_modification;
    }

    public Articles(Long id_article, String type_article, String nomenclature,
            String designation, String unite, String description,
            Long quantite, Long seuil_minimum,
            Fournisseurs fournisseur) {
        super();
        this.id_article = id_article;
        this.type_article = type_article;
        this.nomenclature = nomenclature;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.unite = unite;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantite = quantite;
        this.seuil_minimum = seuil_minimum;
        this.fournisseur = fournisseur;
    }

    public Articles(String type_article, String nomenclature,
            String designation, String unite, String description,
            Long quantite, Long seuil_minimum,
            Fournisseurs fournisseur) {
        super();
        this.type_article = type_article;
        this.nomenclature = nomenclature;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.unite = unite;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantite = quantite;
        this.seuil_minimum = seuil_minimum;
        this.fournisseur = fournisseur;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_article")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId_article() {
        return id_article;
    }

    public void setId_article(Long id_article) {
        this.id_article = id_article;
    }

    public String getType_article() {
        return type_article;
    }

    public void setType_article(String type_article) {
        this.type_article = type_article;
    }

    public String getNomenclature() {
        return this.nomenclature;
    }

    public void setNomenclature(String nomenclature) {
        this.nomenclature = nomenclature;
    }   
    public String getDesignation() {
        return this.designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }   
    public String getUnite() {
        return this.unite;
    }

    public void setUnite(String unite) {
        this.unite = unite;
    }   

    public Date getDate_ajout() {
        return this.date_ajout;
    }

    public void setDate_ajout(Timestamp date_ajout) {
        this.date_ajout = date_ajout;
    }   

    public Timestamp getDate_modification() {
        return this.date_modification;
    }

    public void setDate_modification(Timestamp date_modification) {
        this.date_modification = date_modification;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getQuantite() {
        return quantite;
    }

    public void setQuantite(Long quantite) {
        this.quantite = quantite;
    }

    public Collection<LignesCommandes> getLignesComandes() {
        return lignesComandes;
    }

    public void setLignesComandes(Collection<LignesCommandes> param) {
        this.lignesComandes = param;
    }

    public Fournisseurs getFournisseur() {
        return fournisseur;
    }

    public void setFournisseur(Fournisseurs param) {
        this.fournisseur = param;
    }

    public Long getSeuil_minimum() {
        return seuil_minimum;
    }

    public void setSeuil_minimum(Long seuil_minimum) {
        this.seuil_minimum = seuil_minimum;
    }
}
```

Fournisseurs.java:

```
public class Fournisseurs implements Serializable {



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5404134101337003305L;

    private Long id_fournisseur;
    private String nom;
    private String telephone;
    private Timestamp date_ajout;
    private Timestamp date_modification;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fournisseur")
    private Collection<Articles> articles;
    public Fournisseurs(Long id_fournisseur, String nom, String telephone,
            Timestamp date_ajout, Timestamp date_modification,
            Collection<Articles> articles, Adresse adresse) {
        super();
        this.id_fournisseur = id_fournisseur;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.date_ajout = date_ajout;
        this.date_modification = date_modification;
        this.articles = articles;
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "fournisseur")
    private Adresse adresse;


    public Timestamp getDate_ajout() {
        return date_ajout;
    }

    public void setDate_ajout(Timestamp date_ajout) {
        this.date_ajout = date_ajout;
    }

    public Timestamp getDate_modification() {
        return date_modification;
    }

    public void setDate_modification(Timestamp date_modification) {
        this.date_modification = date_modification;
    }


    public Fournisseurs() {
        super();
    }   

    public Fournisseurs(String nom, Adresse adresse, String telephone) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.adresse = adresse;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }


    public Fournisseurs(Long id_fournisseur, String nom,
            String telephone, Adresse adresse) {
        this.id_fournisseur = id_fournisseur;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_fournisseur")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId_fournisseur() {
        return this.id_fournisseur;
    }

    public void setId_fournisseur(Long id_fournisseur) {
        this.id_fournisseur = id_fournisseur;
    }   
    public String getNom() {
        return this.nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }   

    public String getTelephone() {
        return this.telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public Collection<Articles> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }

    public void setArticles(Collection<Articles> param) {
        this.articles = param;
    }

    public Adresse getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }

    public void setAdresse(Adresse adresse) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }
}
```

ArticleDaoImpl.java:

```
    public class ArticleDaoImpl implements IArticleDao {

    public Long ajouterArticle(Articles article) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(article);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
        return article.getId_article();
    }

    public void modifierArticle(Articles article) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(article);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();

    }

    public void modifierArticleHQL(Articles article) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("update Articles a " +
                "set a.type_article = ?1" +
                ", a.nomenclature = ?2" +
                ", a.designation = ?3" +
                ", a.unite = ?4 " +
                ", a.description = ?5 " +
                ", a.quantite = ?6 " +
                ", a.seuil_minimum = ?7 " +
                ", a.date_modification = ?8 " +
                " where a.id_article = ?9");
        query.setParameter("1", article.getType_article());
        query.setParameter("2", article.getNomenclature());
        query.setParameter("3", article.getDesignation());
        query.setParameter("4", article.getUnite());
        query.setParameter("5", article.getDescription());
        query.setParameter("6", article.getQuantite());
        query.setParameter("7", article.getSeuil_minimum());
        query.setParameter("8", article.getDate_modification());
        query.setParameter("9", article.getId_article());
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void supprimerArticle(Long idArticle) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Articles materiel = (Articles) session.load(Articles.class, idArticle);
        session.delete(materiel);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    }

    public List<Articles> listArticles() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Articles> result = session.createQuery("from Articles").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    }

    public List<Articles> listArticlesParFournisseur(Long idFournisseur) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Articles a where a.id_article = ?1");
        query.setParameter("1", idFournisseur);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Articles> articles = query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return articles;
    }

    public Articles trouverArticleParId(Long idArticle) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return (Articles) session.get(Articles.class, idArticle);
    }

    public Articles trouverArticleParNomenClature(String nomenclature) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Articles.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nomenclature", nomenclature));
        return (Articles) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    public Articles trouverArticleParDesignation(String designation) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Articles.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("designation", designation));
        return (Articles) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    public Articles trouverArticleParTypeArticle(String type_article) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Articles.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type_article", type_article));
        return (Articles) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    public Articles trouverArticleParDescription(String description) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Articles.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("description", description));
        return (Articles) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Articles> listArticlesParQuantite(Long quantite) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Articles.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("quantite", quantite));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id_article"));
        return (List<Articles>) criteria.list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Articles> listArticlesParTypeArticle(String type_article) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Articles.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type_article", type_article));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id_article"));
        return (List<Articles>) criteria.list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Object[]> listArticlesEntreeSortie(String designation, Timestamp dateMin, Timestamp dateMax) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Articles.class, "articles");
        criteria.setFetchMode("entree",FetchMode.JOIN);
        criteria.setFetchMode("sortie",FetchMode.JOIN);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("designation", designation));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("date_ajout", dateMin));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("date_ajout", dateMax));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id_article"));
        return (List<Object[]>) criteria.list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Object[]> listArticlesEntreeSortie2(String designation, Timestamp dateMin, Timestamp dateMax) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT a, e, s FROM Articles as a, Entree as e, Sortie as s WHERE (a.id_article = e.id_article AND e.id_article = s.id_article AND a.designation =?1 AND e.dateAjout>= ?2  AND e.dateAjout <= ?3)");
        query.setParameter("1", designation);
        query.setParameter("2", dateMin);
        query.setParameter("3", dateMax);
        List<Object[]> results = query.list();
        return results;
    }
}
```

VueArticle.java:

```
...
            btnArticle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 IFournisseurMetier metierFournisseur = (IFournisseurMetier) context.getBean("metierFournisseur");
                 List<Fournisseurs> fournisseurs = metierFournisseur.listFournisseurs();
                 DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
                 VueArticle.list_fournisseur.removeAll();
                 if(fournisseurs!=null){
                     for(Fournisseurs  fournisseur : fournisseurs){
                         if(fournisseur != null)
                         listModel.addElement(fournisseur.getNom());
                     }
                     VueArticle.list_fournisseur.setModel(listModel);
                 }
                 FonctionDAO fonctionDAO = new FonctionDAO();
                 fonctionDAO.update_table_article(VueArticle.tableArticle);
                 App.cl_conteneurPaneau.show(App.conteneurPaneau,"vueArticle");
            }
        });
...
```

FonctionDAO.java:

```
...
    public void update_table_article(JTable tableArticle) {
    IArticleMetier metierArticle = (IArticleMetier) context.getBean("metierArticle");
    List<Articles> articles = metierArticle.listArticles();
    String[] columnNames = {"Id article","Type article","Nomenclature","Designation","Description","Unite","Quantite","seuil min","Fournisseur","Date ajout","Date modification"};
    DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    defaultTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    for(Articles article : articles){
          if(article!=null){
          Object[] object = new Object[columnNames.length];
          object[0]  = article.getId_article();
          object[1]  = article.getType_article();
          object[2]  = article.getNomenclature();
          object[3]  = article.getDesignation();
          object[4]  = article.getDescription();
          object[5]  = article.getUnite();
          object[6]  = article.getQuantite();
          object[7]  = article.getSeuil_minimum();
          object[8]  = article.getFournisseur().getNom();
          object[9]  = article.getDate_ajout();
          object[10] = article.getDate_modification();
          defaultTableModel.addRow(object);
          }
      }
    tableArticle.setModel(defaultTableModel);
    tableArticle.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1200, 70));
    tableArticle.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    tableArticle.getColorModel().getRGB(226);

}
...
```

Comment: Quick solution is add @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) and try

Comment: can u tell me where to add it ?

Comment: Articles.java  @ManyToOne
    private Fournisseurs fournisseur;

Comment: sorry that was bad from me i add it but now the list of Articles is empty.